# How is the "live action" tag to be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that two of the four questions in [live-action](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-action) are about specific live-action productions:

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/33750/2604
- [How much of the manga does the Death Note musical cover?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22942/2604)

Is this (using [live-action](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-action) to designate that the adaptation is live-action, rather than asking about the process of live-action productions) correct tag usage? In my mind, this is equivalent to appending [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) to questions about the EVA manga, the FMA manga, etc., and thus probably not very useful. (I *can* see the use for [fullmetal-alchemist-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-manga) in addition to [fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist), but the fact that the additional tag is specific to the franchise makes filtering questions easier and also removes the search engine visibility problem parallel to the one mentioned [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2432/2604).)

I also tried looking at the tag descriptions, but alas, there weren't any comments on tag usage there.

Answer (score 4):

I believe we need to deprecate this tag, as like in the [question you linked](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/should-we-allow-genre-meta-tags?lq=1) - it's too general to be of much use.

Currently we have a [policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/policy-review-tagging-separate-continuities) to split up larger series into appropiate subseries, but live-action versions are potentially too niche.

There are two questions there that do not have a 'master' series tag though, I propose that we have a [live-action-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-action-production) tag similar to [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) and [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production) to discuss specific questions.

There is a similar policy with [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history), in which there is a [light-novel-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel-history) post which is also specific.

Comment: I feel like including a tag for the live action production makes sense _if_ the franchise has already been split up (e.g. with FMA, which has a live-action film in production) but otherwise agree.