# Proposal: Assign all Visual Art's / Key animes to key tag

Tags: discussion, tags

As I've seen, there's created a tag for some animes from Visual Arts / Key, and also, the Key tag itself.

My proposal, for better searching, are reassign all questions on tags from Visual Arts animes (for example, air, kanon), to the key tag, and also the original tsgs.

Comment: We don't generally do this unless there's a very compelling reason to do so - it creates too much tag clutter (related: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2427/). If you want to search for these tags, just [write a search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanon+or+air+or+clannad+or+planetarian+or+little-busters+or+rewrite+or+angel-beats+or+charlotte) and bookmark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would have any benefit to the questions.

current [key](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key) has only 1 question to it, [Why do Maeda Jun productions so frequently feature baseball?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26278/1587). this question is also the only question tagged with [jun-maeda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jun-maeda).

The Question is about [Maeda Jun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jun_Maeda) who co-founded [Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_(company)) which the mentioned works in the question are Visual Novels Key developed. [senshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1908/senshin) could have just used [angel-beats](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angel-beats), [charlotte](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charlotte) and [clannad](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clannad), [little-busters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-busters) and [rewrite](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) which is the tag limit but says

> Dunno about Air or Kanon, but I'd be surprised if they were devoid of baseball.

so if he had confirmed if they did he can't add all these tags.

Now looking at the some of other questions of each of those tags (i didn't look at all of them) they don't seem to be about all of Maeda Jun's/Key's works but about the individual series. so [key](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key) and [jun-maeda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jun-maeda) should be for the combined set of works who's relation is sharing a Visual Novel Developer/author or about Key or Maeda Jun themselves.